# Unable to access website after adding to route table but able to access that in the destination

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn, routing

I added a custom IP to the route table in my PC:

```
route add 203.29.222.150 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.145
```

And 192.168.1.145 is a VM hosted in my PC using virtualbox and this VM has installed a VPN client which for some security reason, "203.29.222.150" have to be called through VPN so I can use outlook.

What I would like to achieve is to access "203.29.222.150" on my PC but routed through the VM.

[image]

The problem is:
after adding the route, I found the vm suddently cannot access any site (I also unable to access 203.29.222.150 on My PC) after trying to access the website in "My PC" and the below error screen shows inside the VM:
[image] 
Why this happen? To my knowledge, if I'm able to access "203.29.222.150" inside my VM, I should also be able to route "203.29.222.150" to my pc, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but **only if:**

1. The guest (VM) OS is configured to *allow* IP forwarding (routing). If it runs Windows, this may be difficult to enable.
2. The guest OS performs masquerading (SNAT), so that neither the VPN software nor the VPN server will see any "unexpected" source IP addresses. (This is not a general requirement, but it's almost always needed for corporate "client" VPNs.)
3. The VPN software does not deliberately block IP forwarding.

On Windows, "Internet Connection Sharing" should cover points #1 and #2 at once – but, again, as long as the VPN software isn't incompatible and doesn't deliberately block it...

Note: Point #2 is not required for VPN technology *in general*, but it is almost 100% likely to be required for corporate VPNs because you don't have control of the server-side. (For custom VPNs where you *do* control the server side, the real requirement is that remote hosts have a route back to your PC's address.)